# Validation routine not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Every time I click submit when the correct information is not filled in, there is suppoesed to be an alert message for each section and the text is supposed to turn red but it is linking staight to the linked file. If someone could help with this the I would be really greatful.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Exam Entry</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function validateForm() {
var result = true;
var msg="";
if (document.ExamEntry.Name.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter your Name \n";
document.ExamEntry.Name.focus();
document.getElementById('Name').style.color="red";
result = false;
}
if (document.ExamEntry.Subject.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter the Subject \n";
document.ExanEntry.Subject.focus();
document.getElementById('Subject').style.color="red";
result = false;
}
if (document.ExamEntry.ExamNumber.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter the ExamNumber \n";
document.ExanEntry.ExamNumber.focus();
document.getElementById('ExamNumber').style.color="red";
result = false;
}
if (document.ExamEntry.ExamNumber.value.length!=4) {
msg+="You must enter at least Four Numbers in the ExamNumber \n";
document.ExamEntry.ExamNumber.focus();
document.getElementById('ExamNumber').style.color="red";
result = false;
} 
if ( ( Examentry.Exam Level[0].checked == false ) && ( Examentry.Exam Level[1].checked == false )  && ( Examentry.Exam Level[2].checked == false )) 
{
alert 
 ( "Please select you Exam Level" ); 
  return false;
}
if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
<tr>
<td id="Name">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="Subject">Subject</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Subject" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="ExamNumber">ExamNumber</td>
<td><input type="text" name="ExamNumber" Length="4"/>
<front size="1">(Maximum characters: 4)</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="Exam Level">Exam Level</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="age" value="GCSE">GCSE<br>
<input type="radio" name="Exam Level" value="AS">AS<br>
<input type="radio" name="Exam Level" value="A2">A2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the file It links to...

```
<head>
<title>Success message</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1> You entered all the data required </H1>
</body>
```

Comment: I dont see any IDs like Name, Examnumber etc., that you are using in javascript function.

Comment: @Unknown: It is there. Maybe edited afterwards.

Comment: IDs should not have spaces -> `Exam Level`. You can retrieve such elements from using `document.getElementById()` but can't use it like you are doing in your `if` statement

Comment: Ironic that a question about exams and such should have so many spelling errors

Comment: It is for my GCSE controlled assesment. I'm only 15 and spelling isn't my strong point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if ( ( Examentry.Exam Level[0].checked == false ) && ( Examentry.Exam Level[1].checked == false )  && ( Examentry.Exam Level[2].checked == false ))
```

contains syntax errors (space between "Exam" and "Level" ) that are preventing your script from running.
If you remove the spaces between "Exam" and "Level" , it will work:

```
 if ( ( Examentry.ExamLevel[0].checked == false ) && ( Examentry.ExamLevel[1].checked == false )  && ( Examentry.ExamLevel[2].checked == false ))
```

**Update**:You will also need to modify the id tags of the actual HTML elements themselves to remove the spaces. e.g `<td id="Exam Level">` becomes `<td id="ExamLevel">`

I would recommend keeping your browser dev. tools (F12 in most browsers) open when testing things like this, as script synatx errors will normally be flagged right away.

Comment: Yes. Having ID with spaces is a bad idea

Comment: @LatinSuD - :) thanks  - I updated my answer to make it clearer that he should also fix the id attributes!

Comment: Thanks I fixed the Code by using f12 i never new about that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be your problem.  Remove `;`

```
function validateForm(); { //-----> Remove ;
//rest of your code
}
```

Also you should take a look at **`validationEngine`** plugin or **`jQuery validate`**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have removed it and it doesn't work still.